# JPA one web application using several databases

Tags: jpa

I have to develop a web application with Java EE (Servlet/JPA) which will be used by several clients who will have each one his own database. Of course all databases have the same structure.

So my question is:
Is it possible for a JPA application to access to several databases?

Comment: An EntityManagerFactory connects to ONE database. How you then utilise JPA in your situation ought to be obvious based on that fact, no?

Comment: read about `multitenant` concept. http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm

Comment: Thanks, it seems that EntityManagerFactory is the begining of a solution to get dynamicaly an EntityManager

Comment: I tested, and there are problems with transactions, it seems not to be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can. You need more than one persistence unit in your persistence.xml.

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="one" transaction-type="JTA">
    ...
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="two" transaction-type="JTA">
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

you also need to tell your EJB to use a specific persistence unit

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="...")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will have to modify and redeploy the application each time I add a client and his database, and I wish I would'nt have to do that !